# How to use geth devp2p to find nodes on non-ethereum chains?

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, polygon

Non-ethereum chains: other chains use geth such as BSC or ethereum layer2 chains such as Polygon.

I can find ethereum nodes with

`devp2p discv4 crawl -timeout 30m all-nodes.json`

But can't find Polygon nodes with

`devp2p discv4 crawl --bootnodes "enode://0cb82b395094ee4a2915e9714894627de9ed8498fb881cec6db7c65e8b9a5bd7f2f25cc84e71e89d0947e51c76e85d0847de848c7782b13c0255247a6758178c@44.232.55.71:30303,enode://88116f4295f5a31538ae409e4d44ad40d22e44ee9342869e7d68bdec55b0f83c1530355ce8b41fbec0928a7d75a5745d528450d30aec92066ab6ba1ee351d710@159.203.9.164:30303" -timeout 30m all-nodes.json`

At the same machine I run a Polygon full node with `sudo service bor start` and it can auto find other nodes with same bootnodes from official document. Same issue also occurs in [BSC](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/issues/328).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I cant get this to work on BSC or Polygon. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying the exact command out and I can find Polygon nodes. `devp2p discv4 crawl --bootnodes enode://0cb82b395094ee4a2915e9714894627de9ed8498fb881cec6db7c65e8b9a5bd7f2f25cc84e71e89d0947e51c76e85d0847de848c7782b13c0255247a6758178c@44.232.55.71:30303 -timeout 30m nodes2.json`

Comment: maybe you should switch to Polygon codebase and build its version of devp2p.